# cURL POST data with json array getbase API

Tags: php

I am currently trying to add an extra bit of information into our CRM. The previous developer has a json array posting into cURL Postfield. I cant seem to figure of the tag part of the json array. I have tried the below code but it does not seem to work for me.

this is what I have tried and it should work but I think I am missing something
    //"tag"=> "tag name"

```
 //Initiate cURL.
 $ch = curl_init($url);

//Use proxy
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxyHost);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxyPort);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array( "data" => array(

              "owner_id" => $rep,
              "first_name" => "$name",
              "last_name" => "$lastname",
              "organization_name" => "$company",
              "email" => "$email",
              "phone" => "$phone",
              "source_id" => $sourceId,
              "description" => $_POST['url'],
              "address" => array(
                      "country" => $Country
                ),

              "tags" => "tag name",

              "custom_fields" => array(

                            "Number of Seats"=> "$size",  
                            "ip"=> "$user_ip",  

                  ),

              ),
);

//Encode the data into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData); 

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 
(Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4','Accept: application/json','Content-
Type: application/json; charset=utf-8','Content-Language: 
en','Authorization: Bearer ')); 

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//Display status
if(curl_errno($ch)){
  echo 'Request Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Below is an example of the API

```
{
  "data": {
    "first_name": "Mark",
    "last_name": "Johnson",
    "organization_name": "Design Services Company",
    "source_id": 10,
    "title": "CEO",
    "description": "I know him via Tom",
    "industry": "Design Services",
    "website": "http://www.designservice.com",
    "email": "mark@designservices.com",
    "phone": "508-778-6516",
    "mobile": "508-778-6516",
    "fax": "+44-208-1234567",
    "twitter": "mjohnson",
    "facebook": "mjohnson",
    "linkedin": "mjohnson",
    "skype": "mjohnson",
    "address": {
      "line1": "2726 Smith Street",
      "city": "Hyannis",
      "postal_code": "02601",
      "state": "MA",
      "country": "US"
    },
    "tags": [
      "important"
    ],
    "custom_fields": {
      "known_via": "tom"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: From the example you can see that it should be an array of strings, not a single string.

Comment: Whats is the best way to format it I have tried                 array("tags"=> "test"  ),
 and I get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example you can see that it should be an array of strings, not a single string.

To make sure you get an array in javascript and not an object, you need an array with numeric indices that start at 0, so you cannot add a key like you did in the comment below your question:

```
"tags" => array("tag name"),
```

or:

```
"tags" => ["tag name"],
```